# XSLT if string-length() does not work

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to use the length of a string to determine whether it is a date, or a date and time. A date would have ten chars and a date-time would have 24. If it doesn't have a time, then the calendar should interpret it as an all day event.

So - this is the if statement I use:

```
<xsl:variable name="alextest" select="string-length(gd:when/@startTime)" />
allDay:     <xsl:if test="$alextest&lt;12"> true </xsl:if>
```

However the if statement always fails to output true, even when the condition is met.

I've tested the logic in various ways, for example outputting the value of the expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="$alextest&lt;12"/>',
```

which resolves as true, so the comparison works. I've also tried this and it works, which seems to show that the structure is correct:

```
allDay:     <xsl:if test="0&lt;12"> true </xsl:if>,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Alex

Comment: Please print out the value of $alextest and then you will definitely find your mistake.

Comment: There's no bug in the code you've shown us. So there's a bug somewhere else. You need to give us enough information so we can reproduce it: complete source document, stylesheet, and information about how you ran it.

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;` is lower than. `13 < 12` can't possible evaluate to true. I think you'll need either `<=` in the form of `&lt;=` or `>` in the form `&gt;`.

EDIT: the following works as expected, so there must still be something the matter outside of the code you've shown, or maybe the values need adjustment. Make sure your select expression for the variable really resolves to something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <el1>123456789101112</el1>
    <el2>123456</el2>
    <el3>1234567891011121314</el3>
    <el4></el4>
</root>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="test" select="string-length(.)" />
            <xsl:if test="$test &lt; 12"><xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>: shorter than 12&#10;</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But if the date has either 12 or 24 characters, `$alextest &lt; 12` is still always gonna be false.

Comment: thanks, haven't had much sleep, the short date is actually ten chars so it should resolve as true

Comment: Many thanks - my code seems to work if I try it on an online XSLT tester. No idea what the problem is! Could it be a browser issue???

Comment: Possible. Maybe try it in different browsers, see if some dev plugin/developer mode can shed some light.